# Function Count ($array)

Tags: php

The answer is probably obvious for many of you, but : how can I make the function "count" work proprerly ? Here four lines of my program :

```
$liste=array($serie); 
if (is_array($liste))  {
    echo "Dans la proc., Liste est toujours un tableau<br>";
} 
echo "Nb de lignes de la liste : " . count($liste)."<br>";
```

The answer to my `if` is `true`, but *count* is 1 - actually 1163 elements !

Comment: If `$serie` is already an array then just do `$liste = $serie;`

Answer (score 1):

`$liste=array($serie);` this code creating an new array that's why its count is 1. assign it directly as below

```
$liste = $serie; 
if (is_array($liste))  {
    echo "Dans la proc., Liste est toujours un tableau<br>";
} 
echo "Nb de lignes de la liste : " . count($liste)."<br>";
```

I recommend to echo your `count()` inside the `if` statement.